# Android - не могу сделать правильную анимацию

Tags: android, анимация, java, android-linearlayout

Есть LinearLayout, который расположен вверху экрана и занимает всю его ширину. Я никак не могу сделать анимацию, где Layout уходит вверх за пределы экрана и такую же, только Layout обратно опустится. Пожалуйста, подскажите код этих анимаций (желательно не xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,
                    0F, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0F, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0F,
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE, -500F);
ta.setFillAfter(true);
ta.setRepeatCount(0);
ta.setDuration(500);
ta.setStartOffset(offset);
as.addAnimation(ta);

myLinearLayout.addAnimation(ta);
```

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо за быстрый ответ!